# mySQL query with prefix

Tags: mysql

is this possible?

```
SELECT id WHERE user=prefix_*
```

if it's not, how is the way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE user LIKE 'prefix_%'`
should do it.

See: [`Mysql Docs - Like`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: @vpit3833 Actually, no. You posted it at 12:26:51, but edorian at 12:27:17.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE user like prefix_%` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html). Note that you have to escape the underscore, because normally it matches a single character.

```
select id from table
where user like 'prefix\_%'
```

Comment: Hmm, don't think so: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html